# facebook like button in wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-like

For my WP7 app, I have an associated facebook page.  How should I go about adding a Like button in my WP7 app that the users can click to do a LIKE?    Do I create a webbrowser control that opens webpage containing the LIKE button?

Looking for some ideas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applications I made, I created a WebBrowserTask and redirected the user to the facebook page URL.

With current APIs you can not run Facebook tasks. Hopefully in future :)